# Best way to include Bootstrap in a AngularDart app

Tags: dart, bootstrap-4, angular-dart

I’m creating a web app with **AngularDart 5** and **Dart SDK 2.0.0-dev.65.0**. What is the best way to include [**Bootstrap**](https://getbootstrap.com/) in my web app?

Thanks!

Comment: Just the CSS or also the JS? CSS you can just link in the head of the index.html page and use it everywhere.

Comment: Thank you. I would like to include JS also …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There really isn't anything that will stop you from using bootstrap and angular together.

You can link the CSS, and the necessary JS files in your index.html file and they won't conflict as far as I know.

Now there is going to be a lot of overlap between dart:html, and jQuery. Also bootstrap is going to be in the global namespace so it may conflict with CSS styles if you are using other libraries.

Just use the html structure and classes as normal in the angular components. You can use them anywhere because they are in the global namespace.

If you need your dart code to interact with the JS code you can use package:js.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The problem is that those package ([js](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/js)) was update in 2016 last time. And, i tried to use JS with it, but it did not work ...

Comment: Package JS still works today we use it in production. Is there something specifically you are trying to do on the dart side?

Comment: OK, I used js package and I put [CSS](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/#css) and [JS](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/#js) as explained in the previous links, and ... it works! Thank you _very_ much!